# Form required attribute validation error

Tags: html, validation

I'm trying to put the final touches on a site that I'm building and I'm coming up with a validation error that I can't figure out. It involves the use of the "required" attribute in one of my forms. Here is the form code:

```
<div id="sub">
    <form id="subForm" action="MAILTO:tworley1977@yahoo.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        <label class="floatLabel" for="subBox"><b>ENTER YOUR EMAIL IN THE BOX BELOW TO SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER</b></label> <br/>
        <input type="text" name="subBox" id="subBox" size="20" required /> <br/>
    <fieldset id="buttons">
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm using a transitional doctype.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Checking with W3C Markup Validator; this is the error that keeps coming up:

Line 116, Column 69: "required" is not a member of a group specified for any attribute

```
        <input type="text" name="subBox" id="subBox" size="20" required /> <br/>
```

This is the only error that I'm getting, but as near as I can tell, I'm using the required attribute correctly. It renders correctly in the browser and works as expected.

Any thoughts as to why I'm getting this validation error??
Thanks.

Comment: does `required=""` make any difference?

Comment: adding that simply produces a different error:  "there is no attribute 'required'". I do get a little more information with this error though. Would the required attribute not be supported by the transitional doctype for some reason??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `required` attribute is an HTML5 attribute and not allowed according to older HTML specifications, such XHTML 1.0.

Consider using HTML5 validation instead, using the doctype string

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Beware that HTML5 does *not* allow all XHTML 1.0 features, especially if you are using XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

Comment: Thanks Jukka. Made the needed corrections and it validates as HTML5 now. Ended up removing the XHTML declaration altogether since it didn't support my non-breaking whitespace markups.

Answer (score 0):

Write only `< !DOCTYPE html >` and than it will work